# Pointwise/uniform convergence of $(\operatorname{sgn}(\cos \frac{x}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

It's clear that this functional sequence is pointwise convergent as if we fix $x$ then $\operatorname{sgn}(\cos \frac{x}{n}) \rightarrow 1 (n \rightarrow \infty)$.

I don't think it is uniformly convergent, If we let $x_n = \frac{\pi n}{2}$, then $|\operatorname{sgn}(0) - 1| = 1 \rightarrow 1 \neq 0 (n \rightarrow \infty)$

If we take $n:= N+1 \land \epsilon:= 1$ then

$$\exists \epsilon >0 \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \exists x_n \in \mathbb{R} \exists n \in \mathbb{N} : n > N \land |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| \geq \epsilon $$

holds.

is this correct?

Comment: "uniformly convergent" depends on the context. What is the domain? $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Oh dear. the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_{n}=sig\left(\cos\frac{x}{n}\right)$, as we can easily see $f_{n}$ 
converges pointwise to $1$, or more precisely $f_{n}\rightarrow 1$ pointwise, ideed for any fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}sgn\left(\cos\frac{x}{n}\right)=sgn(\cos 0)=1$$ 
Now is not difficult to proof that the convergence is not uniform. Ideed for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ take $x_{k}=(2k+1)n\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then 
$$|f_{n}(x_{k})-1|=\left|sig\left(\cos\frac{n(2k+1)\pi}{n}\right)-1\right|=|-1-1|=2,~ \mbox{ for any } n\in\mathbb{N}$$
which proofs that the convergence is not uniform, or more precisely for any giver $2>\varepsilon>0$ we can find a $x_{k}$ such that 
$$|f_{n}(x_{k})-1|=2>\varepsilon$$ for any integer, so this sequence cannot converges uniformly.